# Firebase web authentication not working(Email&Pass)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was going to make a Firebase web authentication.
I added the needed code for checking whether the user is signed or not, needed code for signing in and also the code for checking errors. But none of em got worked. Please have a check:

Index.html:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Firebase Sign In
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="login_div" class="main-div">
            <h3>
                Firebase Login Sample
            </h3>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email...." id="email_feild">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password...." id="password_feild">
            <button onclick="login()">
                Login to Account
            </button>
        </div>

        <div id="user_div" class="LoggedIn-div">
            <h3>
                Welcome User
            </h3>
            <p>
                Welcome to Firebase web login Page. You are currently logged in.
            </p>
            <button>
                Logout
            </button>
        </div>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAL8dSTuXb92DWu0l78dtV4m4fC8psKeV4",
    authDomain: "groupinger-users.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://groupinger-users.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "groupinger-users",
    storageBucket: "groupinger-users.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "432661298034"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user){
    if (user) {
    // User is signed in
  document.getElementById('user_div').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('login_div').style.display = 'none';
} else {
    // No user is signed in
  document.getElementById('user_div').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('login_div').style.display = 'block';
}
});
function login(){
    var userEmail = document.getElementById('email_feild').value;
    var userPass = document.getElementById('password_feild').value;

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
window.alert("Error:" + errorMessage);
  // ...
});
}
```

styles.css:

```css
body{
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
input,button{
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
input, button{
    font-weight:700;
}
//.main-div{display:none;}
.main-div, .LoggedIn-div{
    width:22.5%;
    margin:0px auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.main-div input{
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:15px;
    outline:none;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.main-div input:focus{
    border:1px solid #999;
}
.main-div button, .LoggedIn-div button{
    background-color:#5d8ffc;
    color:#fff;
    border:0;
    display:block;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:15px;
    outline:none;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    transition:0.3s;
    -webkit-transition:0.3s;
    -moz-transition:0.3s;
}
.main-div button:hover, .LoggedIn-div button:hover{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#5d8ffc;
    border:1px solid #5d8ffc;
}
```

The things that didn't worked are,

1. If the user is signed in, the first `<div>` must be hidden and if the user is not signed in, the second `<div>` must be hidden. But in reality, both 2 of em are being displayed.
2. If the visitors enter **123@gmail.com** as email and **Password** as password, he must be signed in. But the signin function is not working.
3. If any of the JavaScript functions like signin function etc. Is not working, then the web page should show us an alert saying about the error. But the alert is not being popped up.
   Please check this code.
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I) displaying when you try logging in? If there's nothing there, try adding some logging (e.g. `console.log("check");`) in the login method to check if it's being called. If Firebase is returning an error, it should appear in the console.

Also, check if you have [enabled the email/password login method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth?hl=en).

Comment: I've enabled the email-password login mode. Also, I'm trying the code on Localhost.

Comment: Good, you need to put "localhost" as a whitelisted (allowed) domain for authentication in Firebase Console > Develop > Authentication. Also, open your browser console to see any error that Firebase logs -- they're usually very helpful to see what's wrong with the application.

Comment: Localhost will be added in the whitelist by default right?

Comment: I couldn't find that information anywhere, in my apps I explicitly add localhost to the list.

Comment: Localhost is added in the whitelist. Still not working.

Comment: What about the console?

Comment: I could had checked the console. But my computer is not working properly. So, can't see the Dev. Console.

Comment: It'll work in your Localhost too. Can you try this code on Localhost? Then you can access console.

Comment: Try another browser, both Chrome and Firefox have good developer tools. You really shouldn't be coding frontend JS without a developer view.

Comment: My computer is not working. Not the browser. Had to use mobile until it gets repaired

Answer (score 1):

How about adding this into your html for firebase authentication

`<script src="/__/firebase/7.17.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>`

Comment: Hi Vupe1752, while your posted code addition may correct the problem stated in this question, it does not explain why it will correct the issue.  Please consider editing your answer to include information on the actual problem and why the code will resolve it.